# How do I correct a misspelling of a tag by one letter?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

In [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/753/are-there-any-english-translations-of-the-bhavishyottara-purana), I intended to create a tag "bhavishya-purana", but by accident I typed "bhavishya-puranas" with an "s" at the end.  I tried fixing it, but it wouldn't let me put "bhavishya-purana" because it's too similar to a tag that already exists.  Is there any way I can get my accidentally created tag deleted and put the question under the proper tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with the Stack Exchange software ([at least, I consider it to be a problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234309/224428)) - if you have created the tag "bhavishya-purana", you cannot create a tag that differs in pluralization ("bhavishya-puranas") nor a tag that differs in hyphenation ("bhavishyapurana").

The only real solution is for someone with moderator privileges to change the tag to have the correct pluralization. We should have mods in a few days, so I recommend waiting until then.

---

Update: this is done!

Comment: Thanks!  And hopefully you'll be one of them.

Comment: @sunshine agree with you, because community moderator always being too busy. So its better to wait for our own mods. I already have made list of ping for our upcoming mods.

Comment: @senshin Thanks for your help!  It's amazing that you're already using your moderator position to do good.